# Contiguous copy – How do I copy files contiguously?

Tags: filesystems, file-copy, fat32

I want to copy a number of files onto a flash drive such that each individual file is contiguous. They do not need to be contiguous with each other, and can be in any order. The files will be very large – hundreds of megabytes, to gigabytes. No other files on the drive should be defragmented; doing so would waste time and cause unnecessary wear on the flash media.

I want to be able to do this for at least FAT32, but methods for `*nix` filesystems will also be appreciated.

Essentially, there are 2 approaches to this:

- Copy then defragment the files.
- Defrag enough contiguous free space for each file, then copy each file into its place.

The 2nd option would generally be far quicker than the 1st, and would avoid causing unnecessary wear on the flash media, so the 2nd option would be very much preferable.

I don't mind solutions that work offline, but obviously online is preferable.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Flash memory is random access and therefore has no seek times, so the file being contiguous doesn't matter.

Comment: @j883376: I'm well aware of that. It's to use my flash drive as a boot disk for many ISOs, without having to partition/dd and therefore duplicate each one.

Comment: I've never heard of this before - doesn't make it not possible - but I did find this Q&A on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071962/how-to-store-a-file-in-continuous-disk-block-in-linux

Comment: You cannot prevent files being interrupted by the metadata which ext4 writes in certain distances on the disk. I don't know how to calculate this, though. If you cannot accept that then you need to write to a raw disk, avoiding a file system. This can relatively easy be done with LVM (LVs can be fragmented, too! So check with dmsetup). Of course, you need to store the length of the file somewhere in that case.

Comment: possibly related http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68189/a-clever-way-to-defragment-a-fat-filesystem

Comment: Shame that I get down-voted on my first question. Not very friendly. I tried very hard to make sure that is it well composed, and it is useful to me at least.

Comment: @Hauke: I knew this wasn't possible for EXT2 and EXT3, but but I thought that the ‘extents’ introduced in EXT4 made this possible. It turns out that they can't be bigger than 128MiB, which explains why I've never had a typical LiveCD ISO be contiguous by chance (this sometimes just works on FAT32 if the free space happens to be contiguous). Is there another `*nix` filesystem for which this would be possible? Btrfs also has extents, could that do it?

Comment: @Hauke: The fragmentation doesn't matter for LVM since it's just a normal boot, but since I want the ISOs as files _anyway_, I'd be duplicating each one. This is the Live boot method I'm trying to _replace_. Maybe, _possibly_ there's a way to put ‘fake’ LVM metadata in a file near the start of the filesystem (and elsewhere if needed), then somehow point the boot loader to the fake LVM ISO partitions (which are actually just non-contiguous files in a filesystem on a real partition). That way I don't duplicate gigabytes of data, though this method seems far more complex than the defrag way!

Comment: @frostschutz: Yes, it looks like Marc MAURICE and I are both after exactly the same goal, but I'm trying to avoid defragmenting the _whole_ filesystem since it wastes time and causes unnecessary wear. Like Marc MAURICE, I'm reluctant to settle for partitioning (what I currently use) or isoloop (yes, I've already tried that one). The contiguous file method on FAT32 without an optimal way of defragmenting, is already good enough for me to get by.

Comment: I came looking for something similar for NTFS and Windows (need it to add an extra layer of factors for safe recovery of very very large drives), and the existing answers, while very good, don't exactly offer a quick & direct solution. Hopefully this becomes widely known and inspires someone to write a targetted utility.

Answer (score 3):

I have to admit that I don't really understand what you're trying to do but I don't think that matters. I found this tool called `defragfs` which purports to do what you're asking (if I understand what you're trying to do).

http://defragfs.sourceforge.net/index.html

I think the thing with this tool though, is that it defrags **after**, where I think you're looking to essentially guarantee that as you write the file to disk, that it's done so in a sequential manner. According to this StackOverflow Q&A titled: [how to store a file in continuous disk block in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071962/how-to-store-a-file-in-continuous-disk-block-in-linux), it doesn't sound like's is possible given the architecture of how the writes are done.

Just to round out this Q&A I did find the following resources which sound like they might be useful.

- [filefrag man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/filefrag) - tool for reporting a file's fragmentation
- [tutorial on using filefrag](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-find-and-report-on-file-fragmentation/)
- [defragfs website](http://defragfs.sourceforge.net/index.html)
- [defragfs theory behind file fragmentation](http://defragfs.sourceforge.net/theory.html)
- [forum thread from reboot.pro regarding contiguous files in linux](http://reboot.pro/topic/17469-making-file-contiguous-from-linux/)

Answer (score 3):

If you need to do this on linux:

`rsync --preallocate /path/to/source/file /path/to/destination/`

rysnc preallocates a contiguous block of storage and copies the file into it.  Works for FAT and NTFS too.

Just make sure the file does not already exist at the destination, or rsync won't reallocate and re-copy it.  If it is, delete it, Empty Trash to make sure it's really gone, then run this command.

Verify if it copied contiguously:

`filefrag /path/to/destination/file`

"1 extent found" means the file is contiguous.  More than one means it's fragmented.

If it's still fragmented, use `filefrag` to check if the source file is fragmented or not.  If it is, use `rsync --preallocate` to copy the source file in place with a new name, defragmenting the source.  Then rsync it again to the desired destination.  Sometimes multiple rounds of this can reduce both the source and destination files down to 1 extent.

If it's still fragemented after that, then you probably don't have enough contiguous space on the destination drive to hold the full file.  Defragment the full destination drive, or use `filefrag` to check large files on that drive for fragmentation and defrag them in place with `rsync --preallocate`, then try again.

Finally, if you're rsync'ing to an NTFS drive, NTFS reserves a small section at the 3GB point for directory files, which may prevent a file from being contiguous if it overlaps that 3GB point.  See the Easy2Boot discussion on that here:

https://easy2boot.xyz/create-your-website-with-blocks/make-using-linux/#Making_files_contiguous

(Easy2Boot also includes the `defragfs` and `udefrag` utilities for defragmenting FAT and NTFS drives from Linux, which may be useful if you need to defrag a full drive)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible at least for FAT32, however I don't recall the name of the tool.

If I remember right is based on a first call for a full length hole and assign it to the new stream, then the file is read and write on that stream.

It is also possible with NTFS via pre-allocate copy if I remember right.

But, for NTFS compressed files there is no way... since Windows first write the file (non-compressed) and after that it compress the file in chunks... to tell the truth it does that in a pipeline... that is the reason the file get so fragmented (a file of 10GiB can create more than one hundred thousand fragments).

I do not know any tool / command able to avoid that when NTFS compression is enabled. I used a tool a long time ago that had a nice GUI to copy without causing fragmentation in Windows, but I can't seem to recall the name.

So the best I can tell you is to use on windows the command line utility `XCOPY` with the `/J` flag.

It tries to not fragment, ideal for big files if NTFS compression is disabled or you are using FAT32.

Explanation for NTFS compression pipeline fragmentation:

1. Block N will be written on Cluster N
2. Clusters arround N+# will be compressed and stored somewhere else, so clusters between N and N+# will be free, aka, file will be fragmented, very fragmented. 10GiB = 100000 fragments, assuming a compression of 50%, that is why NTFS compression is very BAD. If the file would be compressed first on RAM then sent to disk no fragmentation would occur or at least it can be avoided.

Another side effect of this way of doing things is assume we have 5Gib of free space and I want to write a file of 6GiB that after compressing will take only 3GiB. This is not possible, but if you first move a 2GiB (non-compressible) to another place, then free space will be 7GiB, write 6GiB, compressing makes it only 3GiB, free space will be 4GiB, then put back the 2GiB of original data that we moved and voila all is there and 2GiB free. Point being that if there is not enough space for uncompressed file, it will not be possible to be copied on NTFS and it does not matter if after it would be NTFS compressed there is enough space. It needs all because it first write it without compression, then it applies the compression. Lastly NTFS drivers do that in pipeline so in theory it would still be possible, but they did not change the check free size part.

Windows does not write the file "after" compressing it, windows "compress" the file "after" saving it uncompressed, so for each cluster the hard disk will see two write attempts, first with non compressed data, second with compressed data. Modern pipeline NTFS controllers avoid HDD to see both writes but on first NTFS version the HDD writes the whole file uncompressed, then it compresses the file. It was very noticeable with very large and well compressible files. Writing a file of 10GiB that NTFS compressed down to only a few MiB (A file filled with zeros) took longer to write than writing the non-compressed version of the file. Nowadays pipeline has break that, and now it took a very little amount of time but the prior enough free size is still there.

Hopefully one day the NTFS compression method will do it to a row, so we could get non-fragmented NTFS compressed files without the need to de-fragment them after we write them. Untill then the best option is `XCOPY` with the `/J` flag and `CONTIG` or that GUI tool I can't remember the name of. It was while Windows was only up to XP, and had options to pause, to copy in parallel from HDD1 to HDD2 and HDD3 to HDD4, and of course the one wished, to pre-allocate. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: nice explanations, but a little misplaced in this answer

Answer (score 0):

just found this for FAT32 only:

- [CFSpace](https://github.com/ike9000e/CFSpace)