# How to find if usb hdd is an hdd or a flash drive other than looks.

Tags: debian, usb-drive, ntfs

I have an external usb hdd which is automatically auto-mounted.

```
[$] udisksctl status                                                                                                               
MODEL                     REVISION  SERIAL               DEVICE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ST1000DM003-9YN162        CC4B      S1DC5K41             sda     
HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GH24NS95  RN01      KASD5942243          sr0     
ST2000LM003 HN-M201RAD    2BC10007  S34RJ9AFC80519       sdb
```

Now as can be seen /dev/sda is my internal HDD while sdb is the external usb hdd. Now I saw [A clever way to defragment a FAT filesystem?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68189/a-clever-way-to-defragment-a-fat-filesystem)

I tried to run the model number via search-engine and saw that the same model number is given to Samsung as well. I recalled that Seagate had bought Samsung in 2k11 and I bought this hdd a year or two down the road.

http://www.reuters.com/article/us-samsung-seagate-idUSTRE73I1CG20110419

Now on the external case cover it says Seagate so I have to presume/assume it is a Seagate and because it is rectangular in shape, I am assuming it is the old/regular magnetic arm-based hdd. But is there anyway to confirm the same in Debian ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `hdparm` can talk to the drive, and the drive supports ATA-9, you'll see a line in the output of `hdparm -I` with the appropriate info:

```
        Nominal Media Rotation Rate: 7200
```

(for a 7200 RPM rotating drive)

```
        Nominal Media Rotation Rate: Solid State Device
```

(for a solid state device).

Comment: That worked. 

`[$] sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdb | grep Nominal
                                                                                         
 Nominal Media Rotation Rate: 5400`